# LINQ query doesn't give any results (finding which interval a number belongs to)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a property class which looks like this

```
ZipStart | ZipEnd | Acode

10000    | 13999  | BEK

14000    | 14999  | ATE
```

Now, I have a value, for example 11332 and I want to look up which Acode that number belongs to, for this I've the following code:

```
           var res = from o in ListOfDataClass
                  where iCode >= o.ZipStart && o.ZipEnd <= iCode
                  select o;

            var c = res.FirstOrDefault();
            return c.Acode;
```

However this results in  null from time to time, I haven't been able to find a pattern yet though, but since the issue arises in this method I've been able to deduct from the debugger that the iCode IS actually 11332 but that the LINQ-query doesn't yield any results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your condition is incorrect.
The second part has to be `o.ZipEnd >= iCode` or `iCode <= o.ZipEnd`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to move your condition about a little:

```
where iCode >= o.ZipStart && iCode <=  o.ZipEnd
```